# Using for loops with a list of tuples

Tags: python

```
tuplelist = [('John', 'David', 'Roger'), ('Linda', 'Jane', 'Siri')]
counter = 0
for x in tuplelist:
    if counter != 0:
        print(' likes ' + x[0])
    print(x[0], end='')
    counter += 1
```

I'm trying to find a good way to print the following using the list of tuples from the code above:

> John likes Linda
>
> David likes Jane
>
> Roger likes Siri

The code above is my current attempt, which only prints "John likes Linda". I haven't found a solution to do this all at once. I could technically copy-paste the code twice and insert x[1] and x[2] in each block respectively. However, I've read that repetitious code is not good practice, so I was hoping some of you could help me in figuring out a more elegant solution.

Thank you very much for your help in advance

Comment: `for first, second in zip(*tuplelist):`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use build-in function `zip`

```
for man, woman in zip(*tuplelist):
    print(man, 'likes', woman)
```

Comment: @Drako yes, fstings are really great, but they are introduced in python 3.6, and I don't know which version use OP

Answer (score 1):

Although I think the answer by Relandom is the better and more pythonic appraoch, I would like to give you a second answer, pursuing the appraoch you tried (and might be easier to understand for beginners):

```
tuplelist = [('John', 'David', 'Roger'), ('Linda', 'Jane', 'Siri')]

counter = 0
for y in tuplelist[0]:
    print(f'{y} likes {tuplelist[1][counter]}')
    counter += 1
```

As you can see, we're still iterating over something. This time not the `tuplelist`, but the first tuple in this list (the male names). Sticking to your concept of a `counter` variable within the loop, we use this variable to access the second tuple (`tuplelist[1]`) in your list and get the respective value (=female name).

Comment: Thank you, trotta. That was really helpful!

Comment: I would precise that f-strings are python3.6+ and maybe introduce the keyword `enumerate` that replace beautifully the counter approach.